# System Architecture : How to Use the same Banner ( like google banner ) in multiple different websites hosted in different domains or subdomains )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, architecture, cross-domain, oauth-2.0

I have a new big project with ASP MVC 4 and I will need to build in the future a lots of tiny web application that contains:

- A Banner ( like Google banner in black , for authentication, notifications , search …… etc. )
- A body that must access the banner info and knows if the user is authenticated or not.

Let me explain, if we look at  :

- Google play (subdomain )
- Google Map (subdomain )
- Google Translate (subdomain )
- Google Gmail (subdomain )
- Youtube **( different domain )**

We will notice that it’s exactly the same banner for all its subdomains and even different domain (youtube ), and they have just the content that changes, and if I’m already authenticated in google play I do not need to authenticate again in Gmail or YouTube .

I want to do the same thing with my websites : 
here a link to explain in images:  http://www.use.com/ba3e6c12424c7696be7f

### My Questions or just need for confirmation:

1- It is possible to host a banner and websites in different domains and still not authenticate again in every websites? I ‘am thinking about YouTube domain and google domain which is possible. How can I get the same experience?

2 -I assume it’s very easy with subdomains without the need of OAuth 2 for authentication just the normal ASP MVC 4 simple membership will do the job, am ‘I right?

3- Assuming I choose ASP MVC 4  simple membership with subdomains , how can I organize my projects so I don’t have duplicated code for my banner in every project if i want the same experience as google banner ?

a) First idea is to build the banner, put it in an assembly and Render It with an HTML helper, is that a good option? )

b) Do I still have the same experience if I host every subdomain in a different server?

c) Can I choose to host the banner in subdomain1 and load It in a website in subdomain 2 with JavaScript? (do I still have the same experience)

4- Assuming I have to give every website in different domains (not subdomains), how can I manage the architecture? I just need some clues.

5- If I’m wrong on everything, can you guide me to have the exact same experience with complete different domains, or different subdomains with an elegant solution ?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my bad English (third language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two separate questions here. First, how to include a bit of HTML in multiple projects. There's really a myriad of possibilities here. If all of your sites are in the same solution in Visual Studio, the easiest method is to simply pick one project to hold the partial view for the banner and then link to it in your other projects. You do this by right-clicking somewhere in your project in the Solution Explorer and choosing Add -> Existing Item..., find the file in the other solution, but instead of "Add" to confirm, click the arrow next to it, to expand the dropdown and choose "Add As Link".

Alternately, or if one or more of your sites is not in the same solution or is in another language altogether, then your best bet is probably just to save the snippet of HTML as a flat file, somewhere each site will have access to. Then, you just read in from this file and display it.

Your second question is more complicated: how to share authentication. If all of the sites are on the same domain (subdomains), then you can just simply set the cookie on the domain itself, and all subdomains will receive the cookie and have access to the authentication status. If you have sites on different domains, though, it gets exponentially more complex. You either have to implement something like OAuth, which is awkward if all the sites belong together (i.e. OAuth is only really used to authenticate with third-parties, no one really uses this to share auth between related but different domains.) Or, you basically create a server that provides authentication for the other sites.

It's a kind of complex setup, but you've seen it in action on places like Google-owned properties. When you go to login, it takes you to accounts.google.com, and then you're redirected to the originating site after logging in. Essentially, what's happening is that technically the only place you're "logged in" at is accounts.google.com. If one of the sites in the family needs authentication, it redirects you to accounts.google.com. At which point, if you have a auth cookie already, it's sent and accounts.google.com restores your authenticated session, it then redirects back to the original site, with some token that identifies that you are logged in. Going into all the details and how to actually set this up is far beyond the scope of what can reasonably be done here on StackOverflow, but [this is a really good reference and starting point](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic). Part 1 describes the theory. The next installment details how to set it up.

Comment: Since I will have multiple websites where the number will keep increasing ,and after reading the great article in codeproject the last word i want to hear is "exponential" complexity :D, therefore i'am banning SSO from my list. So a good candidate if I want to use different Domains is OAuth2 or Json Web Tooken. Thank you for your answer :)